# Append value to the end of all pages in WikiMedia

Tags: mysql, mediawiki

Is there a way to append '_TEST' to all pages (excluding Main_Page) in the the database?

Looking at the `page.page_title` in the database the field is hashed so not sure the best method to change it (other than going through each one manually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't touch the database manually, it's just asking for breaking stuff. There is maintenance script [`maintenance/moveBatch.php`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:MoveBatch.php) that renames a batch of pages from shell while maintaining referential and logical integrity.